# Change tempdir() in session (update R_TempDir)

Tags: c, r, cran

I am looking for a way to change the `tempdir()` location after an R session has started. I think it would be required to update the C level global variable `R_TempDir`. What would be a nice way to do this from within R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: Simon Urbanecks [unixtools package](https://github.com/s-u/unixtools) has a function to accomplish this. Below the code (for future reference).

```
set.tempdir <- function(path) {
  invisible(.Call(C_setTempDir, path.expand(path)))
}
```

C code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rembedded.h>

SEXP C_setTempDir(SEXP sName) {
    if (TYPEOF(sName) != STRSXP || LENGTH(sName) != 1)
    Rf_error("invalid path");
    R_TempDir = strdup(CHAR(STRING_ELT(sName, 0)));
    return sName;
}
```

Comment: That's totally right! `install.packages('unixtools', repos = 'http://www.rforge.net/'); unixtools::set.tempdir("/new/tmp/path")` did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

If you unlock `tempdir()` and re-assign a new function to the `baseenv()` it might work:

```
tempdir <- function() "/NewTempDir"
unlockBinding("tempdir", baseenv())
assignInNamespace("tempdir", tempdir, ns="base", envir=baseenv())
assign("tempdir", tempdir, baseenv())
lockBinding("tempdir", baseenv())
```

Answer (score 4):

It's awfully cheesy, but you could just mask `base::tempdir` by saying

```
tempdir <- function() { "[desired temp dir here]" }
```

Then you'd be OK as long as you weren't using code that (implicitly or explicitly) looked in the base namespace before the global environment ...

I really don't see any other way to do this, since it's set at initialization time and not altered thereafter.  In other words, `Sys.setenv(TMPDIR="/home/bolker/R")` doesn't work -- it's too late (as you probably know).

If `tempdir()` were less hard-coded it would be a lot easier ... I don't really understand the design criteria here (or, less charitably, whether there were carefully thought-out design criteria ...).  (I feel similarly grumpy about the hard-coding/design of `.libPaths()`, which is similar ... no way to change things once you're in a running R session.)

Comment: This is not going to work. Most of the functions calling tempdir are actually inside the base package themselves. I really need something that modifies the C level global.

Comment: ps: .libPaths() is actually not that hardcoded. Here is a code snippet to set them: http://pastebin.com/E2sVKr30

Comment: I don't think you can. I think R treats that as a 'constant' once set.

Answer (score 4):

Year 2016, still haven't seen a good answer for my taste and use case.
I faced the same problem and found the following solution is the cleanest from users' point of view:

```
# test.R content
message(tempdir())
```

Now change root tempdir at runtime of a script:

```
mkdir rtmp; TMPDIR=$PWD/rtmp Rscript test.R; rm -rf rtmp
```

Or at runtime of an expression:

```
mkdir rtmp; TMPDIR=$PWD/rtmp R -e 'tempdir()'; rm -rf rtmp
```

It is also worth to mention that a programmer who is writing a script/package that use a lot of space for temp files should handle tmpdir the way @João Daniel mentioned.

Comment: Year 2017, it works perfectly, i don't want to install any other package so i go for this solution and it works thantks !!!

Answer (score 1):

The `tempdir()` function is a nice way to create a temporary directory so you can store files valid during the last of the session. It returns a temporary directory created at the beginning of the session, and is where new temporary files created by `tempfile()` are stored by default.

However it's not related to the working directory. If you want to change the working directory you should use the command `setwd()`.

If you want to change the directory where temporary files are stored, you should set this as a parameter on the command.

```
tempfile(tmpdir="/my/path/to/tmpfile")
```

Comment: I know this. I explicitly want to change the default behavior of tempdir() and tempfile();

Comment: Is something related to this? http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/devel/06/09/0025.html
I could override some System environment variables, but it don't seem to modify `tempdir()` return.