# How to change directory for temporary files - problems with huge temporary raster files

Tags: r, raster, temp, r-raster

I'm desperately trying to `writeRaster()` but, since the raster is quite large I need a lot of temp memory. The space on my `C:/` drive is limited and therefore I want to change the temporary dir to `D:/TEMP/`. I tried different approaches I found on the Internet like:

[Change temporary directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107206/r-how-to-change-temporary-directory)

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-do-I-set-the-Windows-temporary-directory-in-R-td876483.html

etc.

`rasterOptions(tmpdir = "D:/RTEMP/")` didn't solve the problem. Even if it worked while the calculation of the raster, it doesn't affect the `writeRaster()` function.

I would be very thankful, if anybody can help me.

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
`R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`
```

Comment: Are you seriously writing raster objects bigger than your system's RAM, or are you not specifying a file name in writeRaster?

Comment: The raster I want to write has 23GB in the temporary file of the `rasterOptions`. I am specifying a target file. When `writeRaster(r1glcm, "G:/<path>/<filename>.tif", format = "GTiff", compression = "LZW", progress = "text")` The temp is written to C:/users/user/documents/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got to the right answer:

```
 write("TMPDIR = D:/rtmp/", file=file.path(Sys.getenv('TMPDIR'), '.Renviron'))
 write("R_USER = D:/rtmp/", file=file.path(Sys.getenv('R_USER'), '.Renviron'))
```

This changes even the temp-directory of the `writeRaster()` function

**UPDATE:**

for those of you, who might have trouble with this error (due to limited permissions)

```
> write("TMPDIR = D:/rtmp/", file=file.path(Sys.getenv('TMPDIR'), '.Renviron'))
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '/.Renviron': Permission denied
```

i found that

```
rasterOptions(tmpdir = "D:/rtmp/")
write("R_USER = D:/rtmp/", file=file.path(Sys.getenv('R_USER'), '.Renviron'))
```

also solves the issue.