# Setting scratch as temporary directory from R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, scratch-file

I would like to set my temporary directory using the scratch space of the cluster. I have tried various methods and this one: [How to change directory for temporary files - problems with huge temporary raster files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302983/how-to-change-directory-for-temporary-files-problems-with-huge-temporary-raste) but nothing works.

I have to read a large file (12 GB) in R and run some code using it. 
I would like to read the file in this way:

```
library(data.table)
mydata<-fread("path/file")
```

But first I believe it is necessary to set the temporary directory as scratch/ otherwise the job has been killed.
Feel free to suggest any other approach.

Comment: You can just create a folder on /scratch then copy data & R script and run from there. Then delete everything after you get the results. These should be done in your job submission scripts (`qsub`, `slurm`, etc.)

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work...