# Changing the temporary directory in R

Tags: r, renviron

First of all, I am aware of the [following discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364431/changing-temporary-directory-in-r) covering the same topic. However, following the instructions, I can still somehow not change the temporary directory.

I installed Anaconda for my local user and then installed R. When I try to start R, I get the following error

```
Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir
```

The problem seems to be that there is no available space left in /tmp. Unfortunately, I need administration rights to either allocate more space or to remove Rtmp-files.

I followed some answers of the other discussion and changed the TMPDIR path in my Renviron file to a local folder. However, this seems to be ignored since I get the exact same error. My Renviron file look as follows:

```
TMPDIR="${HOME}/user_name/tmp"
TMP="${HOME}/user_name/tmp"
TEMP="${HOME}/user_name/tmp"
```

, where I replace my actual user name with "user_name". I was actually suprised that my temporary directory is a root directory and not under my user.
If someone has any idea what's wrong with my approach, I would very much appreciate some help.