# "Temporary name too long" error that appears unexpectedly using Rnotebook

Tags: r, rnotebook

While working with rnotebook I get the following error getting the output of a linear regression model via broom.

This is a dummy example of what I encounter:

```
    N <- 100
a <- rnorm(N)
b <- a + rnorm(N)
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)

lModel <- lm(b ~ a, df1)

summary(lModel)
```

Then if I want to get the output of tidy(lModel) I get the error:

> Error in tempfile(pattern = "_rs_rdf_", tmpdir = outputFolder, fileext = ".rdf") : temporary name too long

The thing is that I have used the `tidy()` function from broom not long before and got the output.  I wonder what may be the issue, and how it can be fixed.

This is the traceback of the error above:

```
Error in tempfile(pattern = "_rs_rdf_", tmpdir = outputFolder, fileext = ".rdf") : temporary name too long
4.
tempfile(pattern = "_rs_rdf_", tmpdir = outputFolder, fileext = ".rdf")
3.
overridePrint(o$x, o$options, o$className, o$nRow, o$nCol)
2.
print.data.frame(x)
1.
function (x, ...) UseMethod("print")(x)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, that the package has been called from library prior to the use of the tidy() function.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks a lot for the corrections made on this question.

Comment: What OS system are you using? I've seen errors like this on Windows where directories are nested too many levels. The Windows API has a pretty short [maximum path length of 260 chars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). On Unix systems this is significantly longer but there is a max file name length of 255 chars.

Comment: Thanks for this comment @dshkol.  I am using Windows 10 64bit.  Is there an additional configuration I must set?  I am curious about why this behaviour with rnotebooks (or rmarkdown for the matter).  I take the code outside the rnotebook (type it and run it directly in the R console) and it works fine.

Comment: Just adjust your working directory, or the structure where you're saving your tempfile. It's either nested too deep or uses too long names so the path is exceeding Windows' path limits.

Comment: Thanks for this tip @dshkol.  Please make this an answer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Maybe someone else will find this useful later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error occurs on Windows systems when directories are nested too many levels in. The [Windows API has a maximum path length of 260 characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

> Maximum Path Length Limitation
>   In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string" where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)

This is pretty easy to avoid. Just adjust your working directory, or the structure where you're saving your tempfile. Either your file name is too long, or your directory is nested too deeply so the path is exceeding Windows' path limits.

As an aside, on Unix systems this the max path significantly longer but there is a max file name length of 255 chars.

Comment: How do you adjust the structure where you're saving your tempfile?

Comment: You can specify that as an option in your `.renviron` file. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108351/3211560

Comment: This Windows issue is painful, why is there this limitation in the first place? I hope someday a new version of Windows ends this misery

Answer (score 4):

This can be fixed with a registry change on Windows 10.

1. Open the registry edit tool by searching `regedit` in the start menu
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`
3. Change `LongPathsEnabled` from `0` to `1`

Now the 256 character restriction will be ignored.

Update Aug 4th '18: If your R working directory is inside a Google Drive File Stream folder then the limit is still enforced. This is because GDFS is a virtual drive that has its own limations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gabriel.

Comment: Unfortunately also not working if dir is within OneDrive (Sharepoint) folder

Comment: I don't understand this at all but it worked beautifully!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: it should be the same registry location. let me know if it doesn't work for you

Comment: My LongPathsEnabled  is already set to 1, but I keep getting the same error.