# Cannot run scripts in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I'm working through some exercises in an Introduction to R book (A Dummy's Book to be specific).   I am running Rstudio version 1.1.447.    I Enter the following script

```
h <-hello
yourname <-readline("What is your name")
Print(paste(h,yourname))
```

I then press Ctrl+Shift+S.    When I do this, I get the following error message:

Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/efami/OneDrive/Documents/.active-rstudio-document': Permission denied

I am running RStudio in Administrative Mode in a Windows 10 system.    I do not understand where this path is coming from (it's obviously picking up something in my environment) or how to get past this problem.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to run software in Admin mode unless you really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why it picked up the directory shown in the error message but the trick is to override the directory by creating a .Renviron file.   The instructions on how to do this are found here:
[Change temporary directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107206/change-temporary-directory)