# Change temporary directory without opening R

Tags: r, ubuntu, tempdir

Today morning when I tried to start R in my Ubuntu machine, I got a new error saying :

```
Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'
```

However when I search over Internet, I realized that my `TMP` directory is full as below :

```
df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       81120924 81104540         0 100% /
```

There is good discussion available how to change that `TMP` directory here

[Change temporary directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107206/change-temporary-directory/17108351#17108351)

However, this requires opening `R` and then change modify the `.Renviron` file. However since I cant open `R` now, I cant use above solution to my  problem.

So, I am looking for some way to modify the `TMP` directory to some other custom folder e.g. `'/opt/R'` without opening `R`

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You could just make the .Renviron file in a text editor outside of R first. It's just plain text as far as I remember.

Comment: Or just empty the temp folder?

Comment: Hi thelatemail, How can I locate the Renviron file without the help of R?

Comment: Hi Roman, I am afraid of emptying the /tmp folder - not sure if any other program(s) are using it.

Comment: On Linux the .Renviron file is searched in your HOME folder. However, you should still check why /tmp is full.

Comment: @Bogaso, hi, I ran into the same issue, can you share your solution if you overcame this problem? Thank you!