# Unexpected CURL error: couldn't open file error in r

Tags: r

I am trying to build a model in r. This is the code which i have used:

```
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
model = h2o.deeplearning(y = 'Exited',
                         training_frame = as.h2o(training_set),
                         activation = 'Rectifier',
                         hidden = c(5,5),
                         epochs = 100,
                         train_samples_per_iteration = -2)
```

And this is the error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix,  : 
  Unexpected CURL error: couldn't open file "C:/Users/WÄ°N10/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4aOzax/file4f04bf12e34.csv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your path has a special character that breaks when running the model:

```
"C:/Users/WÄ°N10/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4aOzax/file4f04bf12e34.csv"
```

I've tried a [quick google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So2PG.png), and it seems that this error occurs with people who have special characters in their languages.

Try running the model with a different user (with no special characters) in Windows and check if it works fine.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you could try to [change the temporary directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107206/change-temporary-directory) to a folder with no special characters.