# Changing Directory for Temporary R Files

Tags: r, windows

I'm working on a Windows machine and I would like to change the location where the temporary files are stored (from C: to G: drive).

I have tried doing so in three different ways:

```
write("TMPDIR = G:/temp", file=file.path(Sys.getenv('R_USER'), '.Renviron'))
```

or

```
tempfile(pattern = ".Renviron", tmpdir = "G:/temp")
```

or

```
tempfile(tmpdir = "G:/temp")
```

but in each case when I go ahead and check with `tempdir()` I find that the location is still the initial one. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart the application before checking the value? TMP or TEMP are environment variables. An application's environment is loaded on application start. Hence any change in environment variables is not reflexted till application restart

Comment: @GaneshR. yes I have.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322451/change-tempdir-in-session-update-r-tempdir and https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/unixtools/set.tempdir.html

Comment: So, surprisingly, if I change the temporary directory in R and restart it, it doesn't work. However, if I change the temporary directory in R and I restart R studio instead, it does work. How is this possible?

Comment: May be the R code is hosted and executed in RStudio and not a separate executable

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows. It will probably work.

```
write("TMPDIR = G:\temp\", file=file.path(Sys.getenv('TMPDIR'), '.Renviron'))
write("R_USER = G:\temp\", file=file.path(Sys.getenv('R_USER'), '.Renviron'))
```